# Longtable too wide

Tags: longtable

I've created a longtable which is too wide. Reducing the fontsize is not an option because of my university's guidelines. I already tried to solve the problem by using resizebox, tabularx etc. but none of this really worked. Since I am really a beginner I might just did a easy mistake.

However, that's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}llrrr@{}} 
\caption{Industry-specific drivers of final energy demand and emissions}\\
\label{tab:IndDrivers}

\textbf{Product} & \textbf{Period} & \textbf{Production growth}  & \textbf{Energy efficiency} & \textbf{Emission share}               \\
& \textbf{} & \textbf{[\% p.a.]}  & \textbf{[\% p.a.]} & \textbf{outside EU ETS} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
Aluminium        & until 2020     & 0.7  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 0.6  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 0.5  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 0.3  &  &  \\
Ammonia          & until 2020     & 1.2  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 1.1  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 1.1  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 1.0  &  &  \\
Cement           & until 2020     & 0.6  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 1.2  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 1.0  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 0.8  &  &  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Does someone have a solution? I'd be very very thankful!

Best,

Fabian

Answer (score 1):

With `makecell`you can add breaks in the tablehead.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{makecell} % ADDED
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}llrrr@{}} 
\caption{Industry-specific drivers of final energy demand and emissions}\\
\label{tab:IndDrivers}

\thead{Product} & \thead{Period} & \thead{Production\\growth}  & \thead{Energy\\efficiency} & \thead{Emission share\\outside EU ETS}               \\
& \thead{} & \thead{[\% p.a.]}  & \thead{[\% p.a.]}  \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
Aluminium        & until 2020     & 0.7  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 0.6  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 0.5  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 0.3  &  &  \\
Ammonia          & until 2020     & 1.2  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 1.1  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 1.1  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 1.0  &  &  \\
Cement           & until 2020     & 0.6  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 1.2  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 1.0  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 0.8  &  &  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If this is the solution you wanted, please accept it as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant using nested table instead of [makecell](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell), headings aligned at the bottom baseline and using better spaces rules from [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). The nested tables are put inside the new command `\thead`. I have used more spacing between rows (`\extrarowheight`) and reduced the dominance of headers by setting them a grade smaller and not using bold.

I have used longtable’s built in `\caption`-command. In the updated answer, I have introduce some reading guidance by using `\addlinespace` to increasing the space between each group of rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, array}

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line of the whole is at the top row.
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}%
    \small\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}llrrr@{}} 
\caption{Industry-specific drivers of final energy demand and emissions\label{tab:IndDrivers}}\\

\thead{Product} &
\thead{Period}   &
\thead{Production\\growth\\{}\footnotesize{[\% p.a.]}}&
\thead{Energy\\efficiency\\{}\footnotesize{[\% p.a.]}}   &
\thead{Emission\\ share outside\\ EU ETS}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot

Aluminium        & until 2020     & 0.7  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 0.6  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 0.5  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 0.3  &  &  \\ \addlinespace[0.75ex]
Ammonia          & until 2020     & 1.2  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 1.1  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 1.1  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 1.0  &  &  \\ \addlinespace[0.75ex]
Cement           & until 2020     & 0.6  &  &  \\
                 & 2021 to 2030   & 1.2  &  &  \\
                 & 2031 to 2040   & 1.0  &  &  \\
                 & after 2040     & 0.8  &  &  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whit this simple change in headers:

```
\textbf{Product} & \textbf{Period} & \textbf{Production}  & \textbf{Energy} & \textbf{Emission}   \\
& \textbf{} & \textbf{growth}  & \textbf{efficiency} & \textbf{share outside} \\    
& \textbf{} & \textbf{[\% p.a.]}  & \textbf{[\% p.a.]} & \textbf{EU ETS} \\
```

You obtain:

[image: New table]

And instead of `until` and `after`, you can write `< 2020` or `> 2040`, and so on...